# Javascript Start counter when in field of view

Tags: javascript, counter, viewport

I need your help because I've been on a project for hours and can't make any headway. An "animated" counter is to be installed on our website. This shows, for example, the monthly cost savings. The following code works great so far.

```
    <script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var ersparnis = 4600;

var inv = setInterval(function() {     
    if(ersparnis < 4800)
        document.getElementById("counter_ersparnis").innerHTML = ++ ersparnis;
    else
        clearInterval(inv);
}, 500 / 100);
/*]]>*/
</script>
<h2>
    + <span id="counter_ersparnis"></span> €
</h2>
```

But now I want the Javascript to start only when the user scrolls to the relevant point. I have now tried to do this with a jQuery code from the Internet, but without success!

```
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery.fn.isOnScreen = function()
{
 var win = jQuery(window);
 var viewport = {
  top : win.scrollTop(),
  left : win.scrollLeft()
 };
 viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
 viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
 var bounds = this.offset();
 bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
 bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
 return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};

jQuery(window).scroll(function()
{
 if(jQuery('#element').isOnScreen())
 {
var ersparnis = 4600;

var inv = setInterval(function() {     
    if(ersparnis < 4800)
        document.getElementById("counter_ersparnis").innerHTML = ++ ersparnis;
    else
        clearInterval(inv);
}, 500 / 100);
/*]]>*/
</script>
<h2>
    + <span id="counter_ersparnis"></span> €
</h2>
 } }
```

By the way, the whole thing should be implemented on a Jimdo site, so I also added the database with the following code in the head area.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You might hear it already, I'm not really familiar with CSS / HTML and Javascript. So it would be great if someone could offer me a plug and play solution. I usually get it rewritten, but not tinkered together (because I want three of these counters next to each other.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `#element` with the actual id `#counter_ersparnis`?

Answer (score 1):

Try This im not a big proponent of jquery so its plain JavaScript.

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector('#element');
let isCounting = false;
var inv;

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const bounding = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        if(!isCounting ){
        var ersparnis = 4600;

        inv = setInterval(function() {     
            document.getElementById("counter_ersparnis").innerHTML = ++ ersparnis;
        }, 500 / 100);
        isCounting = true;
        }
    }else{
        isCounting = false;
        clearInterval(inv);
    }
});
```

To make the code a bit cleaner and reuseable you could do this.

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector('#element');
let isCounting = false;
let inv;

const isVisible = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

function startCounter(){
    var ersparnis = 4600;

    inv = setInterval(function() {     
        document.getElementById("counter_ersparnis").innerHTML = ++ ersparnis;
    }, 500 / 100);

    isCounting = true;

}

function stopCounter(){

    clearInterval(inv);
    isCounting = false;
    
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    const visible = isVisible( targetElement );
    if( visible && !isCounting ){
        startCounter();
    }else if( !visible && isCounting ){
        stopCounter();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond.

Both codes can be implemented, but they are both without function. It just shows me the currency symbol instead of the numbers. Strangely enough, the two counters no longer work when I insert this script, although all three are individually defined. So e.g. counter_saving, counter_sparquote and counter_kosten.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport:

```
let options = {
  root: null, //--> viewport if it is null
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

const callback = function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    let ersparnis = 4600;
    const inv = setInterval(function() {
      if (ersparnis < 4800)
        entry.target.innerHTML = ++ersparnis;
      else
        clearInterval(inv);
    }, 500 / 100);
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

const target = document.querySelector('#counter_ersparnis');
observer.observe(target);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't get that implemented for me. How do I have to change it so that it also outputs the text in h2, like with my previous code?

Comment: @D.Fuchs1996 See this working example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tjzhkx?file=index.html, you can disconnect the observer, also you can check if the node it is not visible to stop the interval..etc